# JavaScript to make some calculations and pass data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is what I want to do:

When a HTML form is submitted, the form data is passed to JavaScript to do some calculations, then the form data along with the results (of JavaScript calculations) are passed to PHP to save data to the database.

Now, I know how to pass form data to JavaScript (or) PHP alone. But how to pass the data to both of them at the same time? And how to pass JavaScript data to PHP?

Also, am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: It's possible, but... can't you do this calculations in PHP only? Why do you need to make them in the client side?

Comment: I question the need for javascript as well in my answer. Remember, users can always tamper with data handled client-side. Don't trust calculations or final numbers coming through from the user input. Sanitize/filter the data, do the calcs server-side, then present the totals

Comment: In modern web scale development, rendering/calculations are being moved more and more to the client side. It's what separates us from 2010 and earlier.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn I wish to use client side for the maximum possible effect to reduce server costs.

Comment: @Zhube, I do not have enough context on this specific problem to talk more about, but if he wants his calculation to be tamper-safe, he would have to check if the result is correct on the server side also. As he is sending a form with the values instead of rendering them in the page, doing the calculation in the client side before sending seems like a unnecessary extra step.

Comment: @Zhube: *In modern web scale development, rendering/calculations are being moved more and more to the client side*... that make sense when you are managing live data, animations, etc

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn: He never said he was processing sensitive data. Rendering HTML/etc is better done on the client.

Comment: @Zhube: He never said he need to render HTML, he only says *...to do some calculations* and after that *...save the data in database*.

Comment: @Tom: I am in no way saying that there should be no server validation. I was pointing out that OP wanted to offload to the client to reduce server strain. That involves creating a concrete path for the information to flow along from client to database, and a solid plan for implementing it. The question he is asking is not quite as simple as "just do it in PHP."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Make calculations in Server Side:

*"I wish to use client side for the maximum possible effect to reduce server costs"* is not the best reason for doing so, if the calculations are not O(4^n), you should go ahead with doing this in the server side.

```
$myvariable = $_POST['numbers']; //I will skip sanitize
SomeCalculations($myvariable); //Making the calculations
```

#### 2. If you really want to use Javascript:

If you really want to use `javascript` (I will use Jquery for simplicity) for learning or because you really think that is necessary in this case, then you can get the form data before submit and doing the calculations:

2.1 Submit the form like a normal form after make the calculations:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var $this = $(this)
    var formData = $this.serialize()
    // do some calculations
    var yourData = makeCalculations(formData);
    $(this).submit();
});
```

2.2 Submit the form via Ajax (recommended since you are already using Javascript)

```
 $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var $this = $(this)
        var formData = $this.serialize()
        // do some calculations
        $.ajax({
            type:  "POST",
            url:   "http://nakolesah.ru/",
            data:   makeCalculations(formData),
            success: function(msg){
                //This is returned in the server side
                alert('wow'+msg);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do the needed calculations on PHP end? It's much easier and saves you headache making sure the data isn't tampered with, etc. The data is being passed there already.

Anyway - You'd either need to have javascript monitor the form and run the calculations as the user completes it. You can:

- store those values in other (hidden?) form fields, which then get passed to php
- use php to do the same calcs (not recommended)
- cancel the form send action and send the data via ajax

Comment: I wish to use client side for the maximum possible effect to reduce server costs.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by server costs? It doesn't really sound like a problem. Please provide more information about what kind of calculation you are doing.

Comment: Doing calculations server-side is extremely, extremely inexpensive from a performance standpoint. Doing it server-side is much more secure and it's important to keep all logic in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX method for your stuff. `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` and etc. you can use any one of the method for your use.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Ref - POST: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to pass data to both PHP and JavaScript at the same time, I can think of only one method. It's not really simultaneous but it's very close to it.

So, let us say that you have this form `#myAwesomeForm`.

Write a JavaScript like this (assuming you are using jQuery [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)):

```
$( '#myAwesomeForm' ).submit( function( e ) {
 var result = someAwesomeFunction() // this will do your calculation and return it
 $.post(
   'someAwesomePHPScript.php',
   {
     formData: $( this ).serialize(),
     calculatedData: result
   }, function( data ) {
     // some more awesome stuff happens here
   }
 );
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to pass the data without changing the page, then use **AJAX**.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Otherwise use `window.location("someFile.php?var1=xyz&...");`

Comment: AJAX *may* work but i doubt it's the right soltion, but redirecting the user's location with form values in the query string is just plain unsafe